# How to add images (as entity) in ckeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg, media

The background: I'm creating an asset management system with Drupal, so for this purpose I've created a content type called `Image` which has an image (widget) attached to it. I then use module [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to link this content type with other content types (for instance, `Article`).

So far so far. This works for my requirements, however I'd like to:

1) Add the ability to upload a new image (therefore new node) from within `Article`
2) Use an existing entity (previously created) within CKEditor in `Article`

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at something like [Shortcode module](https://www.drupal.org/project/shortcode). In general you are looking to insert a token for your image entity.

Comment: That sounds good, however I'd like the ability to resize/crop/move the image. It seems Shortcode module doesn't allow for that...

Comment: Resize/crop type functions can come from modules like [Manual Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/manualcrop). I have used that with Media and CKEditor, but not quite the same way as your implementation. [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) might be something to explore